# G-sheaves on spaces with a free G-action

Tags: sheaf-theory, covering-spaces, equivariant

Let $X$ be a topological space
equipped with an action of a group $G$. In the Tohoku paper, Grothendieck defined
"$G$-sheaves" on $X$ as sheaves equipped with $G$-action on the etale space,
compatible with the $G$-action on $X$. It is more or less the same
as $G$-equivariant objects in the category of sheaves on $X$ with respect
to $G$ acting on this category by endofunctors, but the notion of "$G$-equivariant sheaves" is taken over by sheaves equivariant with respect to a group scheme
or to a continuous action of a topological group.

Suppose now
that the action of $G$ on $X$ is free. Then the
category of $G$-sheaves on $X$ is equivalent to the category
of sheaves on $X/G$. I need this statement when $G$ acts on a manifold $X$ properly
discontinuously, but I suppose this is true in all generality.
I have a proof which works (at least for properly
discontinuous actions), but it's a bit too long for such a
classical-looking statement, so I am asking for a reference
I can use for this. I spent quite a few hours googling and browsing the Stacks Project, without avail.

Comment: My belief, but I am no expert, is that $G$-sheaves on $X$ are basically sheaves for the transformation groupoid $G\ltimes X$.  The free action makes this transformation groupoid principal and  I think under reasonable hypotheses, like properly discontinuous action, the orbit space of this principal groupoid is Morita equivalent to the groupoid and hence has an equivalent category of sheaves.  But I don't know the technical hypotheses to make this work 100% off the top of my head.  So maybe the groupoid literature might come up with an answer.

Comment: See example 32 of https://personal.psu.edu/pxx2/book.pdf for instance.

Comment: You do need the action to be free and proper in general for this to be true.

Comment: well, in my case it is a non-ramified covering of smooth manifolds